# Acceptance testing, docker and selenium

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, webdriver-io

I m trying to create some containers that aim to build my javascript application.

Here's what I need to do :

- Install my dependencies
- Starting my unit tests
- Building my project
- Starting my acceptance tests

Here's my project dockerfile :

```
FROM node:6.9

# Enviroment variables
ENV HOMEDIR /data

RUN mkdir -p ${HOMEDIR}
WORKDIR ${HOMEDIR}

# install all dependencies
ADD package.json ./
RUN npm install

# add node content initially
ADD . .
CMD CI=true npm test && npm run build && npm run test:acceptance
```

The fact is that when I start my acceptance tests, I need to use a selenium server and a phantomjs browser. This way, and thanks to the stackoverflow community, I created a docker-compose.yml file that looks like :

```
version: '2'
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  phantomjs:
    image: akeem/selenium-node-phantomjs
    depends_on:
      - hub
    links:
      - hub
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - hub
      - phantomjs
```

My selenium-phantomjs well connects to my selenium/hub, and selenium is available at localhost:4444 on my host machine.

My real problem is that my tool to achieve acceptance testing (webdriverio) doesn't seem to be able to contact the selenium server, and I don't know why.

I'm having the following stack :

```
app_1        | [08:24:07]  COMMAND  POST     "/wd/hub/session"
app_1        | [08:24:07]  DATA     {"desiredCapabilities":{"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"maxInstances":5,"browserName":"phantomjs","loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","driver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io","version":"4.6.1","name":"webdriverio"}}}
app_1        | ERROR: Couldn't connect to selenium server
app_1        | phantomjs
app_1        | Error: Couldn't connect to selenium server
app_1        |
app_1        | Wrote xunit report to [./xunit].
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your test-scripts from within another container, then the `wd_host` parameter needs to be set to `http://hub:4444/wd/hub`, instead of `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` (default).

The `links:` field makes `hub` available under the hostname `hub`, not as `localhost`, to the other container.

The `ports:` field is only used to access containers from your host machine, it doesn't affect what containers themselves can access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I m trying to find a way to modify selenium host inside of wdio.conf.js x_x. I'll give you feedbacks when this will be working